# Win32: "Save as" dialog file name hint

Tags: winapi, dialog, save

Some "Save as" dialogs provide a default file name - how is it done?

I know how to create basic "Save as" dialog: OPENFILENAME, GetSaveFileName, and all that. But where should I put the string representing, say the file name of currently opened file? I thought it would come from .lpstrFile but this is not the case...

Update: I was not using **static** char path in WinProc. Now I am, and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it *does* come from lpstrFile. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839%28VS.85%29.aspx) says:

> lpstrFile:
>       Long pointer to a buffer that contains a file name used to initialize the File Name edit control. [...]

Maybe you could give a short(!) code example that can be used to reproduce your problem?